# monotouch object not set to an instance. tableview data not populating textviews

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, nullreferenceexception

I have a tableview that holds personal information. The information came from textviews and placed into a array and finally stored on disk in a txt file.
When a person selects an entry to update the personal information I read the file, put the data back into an array and ***want to populate the textviews with the original data*** 
This is my problem statement. I want to populate textviews with data from a file.

I am able to select the person but receive System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am using samples from Xamian and others to populate the tableview. 
My program consists of public partial  class RegistrantScreen : UIViewController that has the textviews and other controls. I used the xib to create the physical interface.
My public class registrantTableSource : UITableViewSource has the normal methods RowsinSection and RowSelected.
I use the RowSelected as the method to learn which person data needs to be updated. When I select a person the RowSelected fires and processing begins. I pass back the selected person index number then read the file and place in an array. When I try to use the array data to populate the textview I get the null reference exception.

Below are the two methods to get person selected index and passing back to the other class.

```
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //myPersonSelected = new RegistrantScreen (facility);
        AnIndexSelected = true;
        //need to read the fac file so we know if on site or off site for populating the boxes.
        int person = indexPath.Row  ;
        //new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show(); 
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); 
        upDateOne (person);//jump over and get the file and fill an array for the person selected.
    }//end of public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)



    public void upDateOne(int rowPerson)//rowPerson is the selected index of registrants.
    {
        string facilityFolder =Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        facilityFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine (facilityFolder , "Facilities");
        facilityFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine (facilityFolder, "tmpFacility");

        string facility = File.ReadAllText (facilityFolder);//has the name of the facility to open
        string tmpRegistrants = facility.Replace ("fac", "par");//this holds the participants information.

        facilityFolder =Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        facilityFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine (facilityFolder , "Facilities");
        tmpRegistrants = facility.Replace ("fac", "par");//this holds the participants information.
        facilityFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine (facilityFolder , tmpRegistrants );//should be reading the par file now.
        registrants = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (facilityFolder);//this is the array for the selected participant.
        //string [] personToUpdate = registrants[rowPerson];
        //fillBoxes (Convert.ToString ( registrants[rowPerson]) );
        //need to populate the text boxes next.
        //need to check for commas again.
        RegistrantScreen myPersonSelected;
        myPersonSelected =  new RegistrantScreen (facility );


        //myPersonSelected .tableIndexChanged (rowPerson);
         myPersonSelected.updateForOne(rowPerson );
        ;
    }//end of public void upDateOne(int rowPerson)
```

Here is where I am passing the data to.

```
    public void updateForOne(int person)//fill the textboxes for one person.
    {
        facilityFolder=Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        facilityFolder= System.IO.Path.Combine (facilityFolder, "Facilities");
        facilityName= System.IO.Path.Combine (facilityFolder, Title);
        facilityLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (facilityName);//get the facility info to use for decision making.
        string participantFile = facilityName.Replace ("fac", "par");
        string [] participantList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (participantFile);//get all the participants

        char [] deLimChars = { ',' };
        string[] words = participantList[person].Split( deLimChars );

        RegistrantScreen myTest = new RegistrantScreen (Title );

        tbXXXXapproval.Text = words[0];  ****Null reference exception here.****
```

I think my objects get garbage collected but have not found the process to keep my textview and other controls from being null.
Any help or pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that `words` is not null or empty?

Comment: words does contain the array values for populating. The textviews themselves are null. I think this is the error but have not found the mix to correct.

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to instantiate the textviews?

Comment: // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   ParticipantTable = new UITableView(new RectangleF(134,400,518,575));
   ParticipantTable.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;

   ParticipantTable.Source = new registrantTableSource(INSTALLcme.registeredPeople);
   Add (ParticipantTable);

Comment: I just realized you asked about textview. The textviews were created with Xcode using the xib files. [Outlet]
  MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField tbFirstName { get; set; }

  [Outlet]
  MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField tbLastName { get; set; }

Comment: Further troubleshooting leads me to wonder if I should change the textfield.text member to be public. Has anyone tried this and have you had negative experiences? The member Text seems to be causing the problem.